# Can I add a gif on top of another gif in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spatial, gganimate

I've got two gifs that I've generated with `ggplot` and `gganimmate`. One is a world map and the other is a normal bar graph. I'm trying to show the bar graph in a viewport inside of the world map and have them be animated at the same rate. Since they're both created using the same dataset, I thought I could use `gganimate` to animate them at the same time.

I'm looking to make something like this:

[image]

The bar graph uses `transition_reveal()` and the map uses `transition_manual()` so I can't animate them together.

Is there a simpler way to animate two plots at the same time? Or can I somehow get both to use the same `transition_*()` function?

Code used for map:

```
plot_anim = ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry,
              fill = Deaths),
          alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = X, y = Y,
                 size = ifelse(Confirmed==0, NA, Confirmed)),
             shape = 21,
             colour = "turquoise",
             alpha = 0.5,
             fill = "turquoise") +
  transition_manual(Date)

animate(p, renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = T))
```

Code used for bar graph:

```
plot_anim2 = ggplot(data = totals) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Date, y = Number,
               fill = Type),
           stat = "identity",
           position = "stack") +
  transition_time(Date) +
  shadow_mark(past = T)  

animate(plot_anim2, renderer = gifski_renderer(loop = TRUE))
```

Edit:

Some data:

```
> head(dat)
        Date             Country Confirmed Recovered Deaths      pop cases_per_mil          X         Y
1 2020-01-22         Afghanistan         0         0      0 29117000             0  66.004734  33.83523
2 2020-01-22             Albania         0         0      0  3195000             0  20.049834  41.14245
3 2020-01-22             Algeria         0         0      0 35423000             0   2.617323  28.15894
4 2020-01-22             Andorra         0         0      0    84082             0   1.560544  42.54229
5 2020-01-22              Angola         0         0      0 18993000             0  17.537368 -12.29336
6 2020-01-22 Antigua and Barbuda         0         0      0    89000             0 -61.794693  17.27750
                        geometry
1 MULTIPOLYGON (((74.89131 37...
2 MULTIPOLYGON (((20.06396 42...
3 MULTIPOLYGON (((8.576563 36...
4 MULTIPOLYGON (((1.706055 42...
5 MULTIPOLYGON (((14.19082 -5...
6 MULTIPOLYGON (((-61.71606 1...
```

```
> head(totals)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Date       Type      Number
  <date>     <chr>      <int>
1 2020-01-22 Confirmed    555
2 2020-01-23 Confirmed    654
3 2020-01-24 Confirmed    941
4 2020-01-25 Confirmed   1434
5 2020-01-26 Confirmed   2118
6 2020-01-27 Confirmed   2927
```

Comment: sounds like an interesting question. Any chance you could share some data with us? I.e., "dat" and "totals".

Comment: Sorry 'bout that, have added some!

Comment: You could try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49511083/2554330, using ImageMagick on the command line, or try the `magick` package in R to do it all in R.

Comment: Unfortunatley this data snippet would not allow us to reproduce the data (see all the ellipses... ) Could you maybe post the full output of `dput(head(dat))` and `dput(head(totals))`

Comment: @Tjebo I ran that in my console but because of the geometry data, the output is insanely long. I'll put it [here for dat](https://pastebin.com/ePxgP6gq) and [here for totals](https://pastebin.com/mnEyD2eH)

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to save your gif files to www folder and display them using absolutePanel in a blank Shiny app.  You can have barplot fade and the other one not fade. Below is a static world map on which two images are displayed in absolute panel. You can drag and place them where you want as they are floating.

[image: output]